Display a telerikgrid in blazor on a button click - wont load
I have a blazor component.
Im trying to display a test table once a button is clicked like so:
<button id="btnKltClms" class="slikaButton" @onclick="TestClick" hidden="@isBtnKltClmsHidden"></button>

  <div hidden="@isTbResultsHidden"> 
 <TelerikGrid Data="@resultTableData">
    <GridColumns>
        <GridColumn Field="@nameof(ResultTableRow_Klt_Clms.CompanyName)" Title="חברה" />
        <GridColumn Field="@nameof(ResultTableRow_Klt_Clms.CompanyNumber)" Title="מספר חברה" />
        <GridColumn Field="@nameof(ResultTableRow_Klt_Clms.DeliveryNumber)" Title="מספר משלוח" />
        <GridColumn Field="@nameof(ResultTableRow_Klt_Clms.RecordedEntriesNumber)" Title="מספר רשומות שנקלטו" />
        <GridColumn Field="@nameof(ResultTableRow_Klt_Clms.ShguimEntriesNumber)" Title="מספר רשומות שגויות" />
    </GridColumns>
</TelerikGrid> 
  </div>

And thats my code behind file:
       async Task TestClick()
       {
           resultTableData.Clear();
           for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
           {
               current_Company1 = $"curComp{i}";
               current_Company_name1 = $"curCompName{i}";
               CURRENT_MISHLOACH1 = $"mishloah{i}";
               TOTAL_SHG_D1 = $"totalShg{i}";
               await BuildResultTable();
           }
           StateHasChanged();
       }

       async Task BuildResultTable()
       {
           resultTableData.Add(new ResultTableRow_Klt_Clms
           {
               CompanyName = StringUtil.Reverse(current_Company_name1),
               CompanyNumber = current_Company1.ToString(),
               DeliveryNumber = CURRENT_MISHLOACH1.ToString(),
               RecordedEntriesNumber = (recordarr.Length - 2).ToString(),
               ShguimEntriesNumber = TOTAL_SHG_D1.ToString()
           });
           isTbResultsHidden = false;
           isLabelErrorHidden = false;
           StateHasChanged();
       }


When I check in debug, obviously the list will include 6 items.
When table is displayed ( after a button click it will display an empty table
Ive been trying to "play" with signatures , async void, async Task, await, not await, all of that.
Ive been also trying to do this
await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());

but its clear that something in that logic is beyond my understanding as of now.
Any ideas?
Thanks !!

You need to rebind the Grid after changing the Data:
At the end of TestClick() add
GridRef?.Rebind();

No need for StateHasChanged.
Also change your grid definition to
 <TelerikGrid @ref="@GridRef" Data="@resultTableData">

And add a variable
    private TelerikGrid<ResultTableRow_Klt_Clms> GridRef { get; set; }


Thank you so much, it is working as expected!
